# Strange border on the tag info page on localized Stack Overflow sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

enSO (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info):

> [image]

This block:

```
<div id="questions">
```

On localized sites (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info):

> [image]

But on localized sites this div has additional classes which cause this issue:

```
<div id="questions" class="bt bc-black-2 mt4">
```

> [image]

Could you fix it?

Comment: affects all sites other than SO, not just international sites

Comment: @YaakovEllis didn't notice that. Thanks)